# sscanf string splitting not working

Tags: c, string, split, scanf

Can someone please explaing why the string is not splitted in the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char name[] = "first:last";
    char first[20], last[20];

    sscanf(name, "%s:%s", first, last);

    printf("first: %s, last: %s", first, last);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

> first: first:last, last:

but it should be

> first: first, last: last

Kindly check code here http://ideone.com/JDSTt

Comment: If you tested the return value from `sscanf()`, it would tell you it only did one conversion, not two as you expected, giving you a strong hint that there was something amiss in your expectations.  Always check for errors...especially when you're baffled by something.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
sscanf(name, "%[^:]:%s", first, last);
```

`:` is not whitespace, so a regular `%s` will not consider it as a delimiter. See [`scanf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/scanf.html) for more details.

(Edited demo: http://ideone.com/m4LVP)

Answer (score 2):

See the [scanf documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/) about `%s` type specifier:

> **String of characters.** This will read subsequent characters until a
>   whitespace is found (whitespace characters are considered to be blank,
>   newline and tab).