# SScanf for CString not working?

Tags: c++, mfc

I just want to split this string by the char ":"
for example "first:last"
so one string will have "first" and the other will have "last"

I did like the one in this url ([sscanf string splitting not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642500/sscanf-string-splitting-not-working))
but it didn't work well with me as both strings will have the "last" value

```
 #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS  
 #include<iostream>
 #include <cstring>
 #include<tchar.h>
 #include<atlstr.h>
 using namespace std;


 void main()
{
    CString firstString(""), secondString(""), myString("first:last");

    sscanf(myString, "%[^:]:%s", firstString, secondString);

    printf("first: %s, last: %s", firstString, secondString);


    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: You can't use MFC strings directly like that for C io input functions. Those need character buffers.

Comment: How is that supposed to work?  `sscanf()` is a C function that will expect to populate a character buffer, not a `CString` object.

Comment: Actually, you *can* do that using [CString::GetBuffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314880(v=vs.60).aspx) and then using `CString::ReleaseBuffer`, but still not the best way to do this.

Comment: Since you are using MFC, you could also do this entirely with the `CString` class using `Find` then get substrings.

Comment: Thank you crashmstr and tojanfoe so much :) it is working now using GetBuffer but what is the best way to do this ??

Comment: MFC/ATL, std namespace, `system` call, `void main`, <cstring> - What is cooking boss? Concentrate!

Comment: If you are going to use MFC (*really* use), you would generally want to avoid using C functions where possible and only use `GetBuffer` where you can't get around it (API calls, etc.). On the other hand, you could just use C style strings here and keep the `sscanf`, since you are not doing anything at all with the `CString`.

Comment: I recommend not using MFC or any microsoft extensions to the C++ langauge.  If you must, keep them isolated from sections with standard C++.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, do not mix C "strings" and MFC CStrings.  Here's a solution using MFC CString:

```
const int iColon = myString.Find(':');
if (iColon >= 0)
  {
  firstString = myString.Left(iColon);
  secondString = myString.Mid(iColon+1);
  }
```