# Why MFC dbgheap.c 1044 line runtime error occurs

Tags: c++, mfc

An error sometimes occurs during program running.
It doesn't happen every time.

[image]

I don't know why I get an error in this part.
The length of strAckData is greater than 13

```
x_FWCommunity->sRevDataStr = strAckData.GetAt(13); '
```

**User SourceCode**

```
void CMLT2App::AckTotalFusingMsg(CString strAckData)
{
  char szLog[512];
  CString strCmd(""), strResult(""), strTemp(""), strLen("");
  char cResult;
  int nCmd = 0, nPos = 0, nDataLen = 0;

  strTemp = strAckData;
  nPos = strTemp.Find(0x02);
  strAckData = strTemp.Mid(nPos, strAckData.GetLength() - nPos);
  if (strAckData.GetAt(0) != 0x02) return; // Check STX
  if (strAckData.GetAt((strAckData.GetLength() - 1)) != 0x03) // Check ETX
    return;

  strCmd.Format("%s", strAckData.Mid(7, 2)); // Get Command;
  sscanf(strCmd, "%X", &nCmd); // String Convert to Hex
  cResult = strAckData.GetAt(13); // String Convert to Decimal    
  x_FWCommunity->sRevCmdStr = strCmd;

  strLen.Format("%s", strAckData.Mid(9, 4));
  sscanf(strLen, "%X", &nDataLen);
  // strCmd 는 0xBD
  if (strCmd == "FE" || strCmd == "5E")
  {
    x_FWCommunity->sRevDataStr = strAckData.Mid(13, nDataLen);
    // AfxMessageBox(x_FWCommunity->sRevDataStr);
  }
  else
    x_FWCommunity->sRevDataStr = strAckData.GetAt(13);    ← Error Point

    switch (nCmd)
    {
    case CMD_CTRL_FUSING_SYSTEM:
    case CMD_CTRL_FUSING_CONTROL_PTN:
    case CMD_CTRL_FUSING_PREDISP_PTN:
```

**Call Stack Log**

```
MSVCRTD! 102136a8()
MSVCRTD! 102135b1()
operator delete(void * 0x01a11f28) line 351 + 12 bytes
CString::FreeData() line 146 + 15 bytes
CString::Release() line 157
CString::AllocBeforeWrite(int 1) line 200
CString::AssignCopy(int 1, const char * 0x01e2e684) line 315
CString::operator=(char 48) line 88
CMLT2App::AckTotalFusingMsg(CString {"A2A100BD002300375000011320373000000630331000000C3"}) line 6029
CMLT2App::RS232C_ReceivedFusingInfo(unsigned char * 0x01e2eb8c) line 5412
ThreadWatchComm1(CPortController * 0x01514010) line 966
KERNEL32! 7c7db729()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, please make sure to take the [tour](//stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Especially: format your code correctly so others can understand it better and please [do not upload images of errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10669875).

Comment: You are corrupting memory, somewhere. Finding out where and when is hard. Try pulling a [Time Travel Debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/time-travel-debugging-overview) trace so that you can navigate back in time, starting from the point where you observe the issue. The information provided is insufficient. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Your codes should add more conditions checking : how about the input string that does not contain '0x02' ?  how about `strAckData` that is empty ? GetAt() function needs a correct index and a correct string otherwise your program crashs.

Comment: From the call stack it appears that the object `x_FWCommunity->sRevDataStr` has been corrupted. Prior to assigning the new contents, the previous contents are cleaned up (`Release()` -> `FreeData()` -> `operator delete`), but the internal pointer appears to be invalid. The corruption could be anything, a stack overrun, heap corruption, or the result of passing a `CString` from one library to another, that happens to use a different `CString` template instantiation. Again, a [mcve] is required to provide a definitive answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SScanf for CString not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552183/sscanf-for-cstring-not-working)